# Validating forms with common rules using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, validation

I've got multiple forms, all of them share common fields (for example `email`), and each one has unique fields (for example, `uniqueFieldA` on Form A, and `uniqueFieldB` on Form B ).

What I want to do: Write a set of validation rules (using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/)) for the common fields *once*, and "include" those rules in multiple places (each form), then add in the rules unique to that particular form.

Something like this:

Simplified HTML:

```
<form id="formA">
  <input name="email" />
  <input name="uniqueFieldA" />
</form>

<form id="formB">
  <input name="email" />
  <input name="uniqueFieldB" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
// Define rules common to all forms
var commonRules = { 
  email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
  },
}

// Define rules for form A
$("#formA").validate({
   rules: {
     commonRules, //"include" common rules
     uniqueFieldA: "required" //rule unique to this form
   }
})

// Define rules for form B
$("#formB").validate({
   rules: {
     commonRules, //"include" common rules
     uniqueFieldB: "required" //rule unique to this form
   }
})
```

What will achieve this (assuming the full, correct HTML was used)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that's not syntactically valid JavaScript ([JSLint](http://jslint.com) could have told you that), **no, it will not work.**

---

[`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend) is your friend here. Try this (not tested):

```
// Define rules common to all forms
var commonRules = { 
  email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
  },
};

// Define rules for form A
$("#formA").validate({
   rules:  $.extend({
     uniqueFieldA: "required"
   }, commonRules)
});

// Define rules for form B
$("#formB").validate({
   rules: $.extend({
     uniqueFieldB: "required"
   }, commonRules)
});
```

You may need to perform a recursive merge (a "deep extend") if there is any overlap between the common rules and the form-specific ones.